# ValueError: The file could not be found with <pipeline.storage.PipelineCachedStorage object>

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to compile SASS and compress CSS files with [**django pipeline**](http://django-pipeline.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) on *Django 1.6.3*, but I get the following error after visiting my site:

> ValueError: The file 'css/test2.css' could not be found with <pipeline.storage.PipelineCachedStorage object at 0x0585DF50>.

I configured pipeline following the guide on [readthedocs.org](https://readthedocs.org/): I added pipeline to `INSTALLED_APPS` then I defined `STATIC_URL` and `STATIC_ROOT`:

```
STATIC_URL = '/test/forum/skins/default/media/'
STATIC_ROOT = '/test/forum/skins/default/media/'
```

Folders tree:

- test

  - forum

    - skins

      - default

        - **media** (static files)

          - css
          - js
          - images
      - site1
      - site2
      - site3
- views
- utils
- settings.py

I added `SASSCompiler` to `PIPELINE_COMPILERS` and then I added the path to the file to be compressed:

```
# pipeline settings
STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'pipeline.storage.PipelineCachedStorage'
PIPELINE_COMPILERS = (
  'pipeline.compilers.sass.SASSCompiler',
)
PIPELINE_CSS = {
    'main': {
        'source_filenames': (
          'css/test.scss',
        ),
        'output_filename': 'css/test2.css',
    },
}
```

Finally I linked the css to my XHTML index:

```
{% load compressed %}
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        {% compressed_css 'main' %}
    </head>
```

I do not understand what I did wrong. 
Thanks for any help!

---

#### UPDATE:

When I run `collectstatic` this copy the files from django and not from my project

```
F:\DEV\DJANGO\apps\test>python manage.py collectstatic

You have requested to collect static files at the destination
location as specified in your settings:

    F:\test\forum\skins\default\media

This will overwrite existing files!
Are you sure you want to do this?

Type 'yes' to continue, or 'no' to cancel: yes
Copying 'F:\DEV\DJANGO\apps\django\django\contrib\admin\static\admin\css\base.
css'
Copying 'F:\DEV\DJANGO\apps\django\django\contrib\admin\static\admin\css\chang
elists.css'
Copying 'F:\DEV\DJANGO\apps\django\django\contrib\admin\static\admin\css\dashb
oard.css'
Copying 'F:\DEV\DJANGO\apps\django\django\contrib\admin\static\admin\css\forms
.css'
Copying 'F:\DEV\DJANGO\apps\django\django\contrib\admin\static\admin\css\ie.cs
s'
[etc .... ]
```

But the path `F:\test\forum\skins\default\media` is wrong, my project is located 
in `F:\DEV\DJANGO\apps\test\forum\skins\default\media`.

Then I tried to find the static file:

```
F:\DEV\DJANGO\apps\test> python manage.py findstatic css/main.css

No matching file found for 'css/main.css'.
```

But the file exists.

Comment: In PIPELINE_CSS for `source_filenames`, I believe you have a typo: `css/test.scss` should be `css/test.css` or whatever the actual file name is (may be test2.css based on your code)

Comment: Thank you so much @Fiver. I tried to use the same name for input and output (test.scss and test.css), but I get the same error.

Comment: Also, I'm not sure it's a good idea to have `STATIC_URL` and `STATIC_ROOT` set to the same directory. `STATIC_ROOT` should be empty as this is where django will move your static files when running `collectstatic`.

Comment: Thanks! I have updated my question with more details. Probably I have a wrong path for `STATIC_ROOT`. Now I will try with `STATIC_ROOT = '\'`

Comment: I think you misunderstood, let me provide further details in an answer

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In Django's `settings.py`, the `STATIC_ROOT` variable tells Django where to move your static files, whereas `STATIC_URL` is the URL path that users will see and from where you can access the files within the browser. See the Django documentation on static files:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#static-files

For example, lets's say you have the following in your settings.py file:

```
STATIC_ROOT = "/var/www/example.com/static/"
STATIC_URL = "/static/"
```

Now, let's you are doing your software development on the same machine within `/home/fuiba/git/your-django-project/`. Within your Django project you have a sub-directory called static, and within that directory you have a file called `custom.css`. The full path to this file is:

```
`/home/fuiba/git/your-django-project/static/custom.css`
```

Now, after running `python manage.py collectstatic` your style sheet is moved to your `STATIC_ROOT` directory. Now you start the web server and you can access the static file via the project's `STATIC_URL`. So, let's assume you run the web server on the localhost on port 8000, you can access the stylesheet from your browser at the following location:

```
http://localhost:8000/static/custom.css
```

Ok, that's the foundation for how it works. In your case, you appear to be developing under Windows, so there's a few caveats. First, don't use backslashes ('\') in your paths, use only forward slashes. However, you still must specify the drive letter and colon. So, let's set your `STATIC_ROOT` to:

```
STATIC_ROOT = "F:/DEV/DJANGO/apps/test-static-root/"
```

I'm choosing this so you don't pollute your test project directory, and a sibling directory should be created in the above location with your static files within.

Let me know how you get along, and I'll try to provide more details.

Good luck!

Comment: Thank you so much for your very comprehensive and clear answer.